# What do you call a person who completed prerequisite classes for a master's degree but didn't finish their thesis?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I don't necessarily mean a single word, but a short, precise and neutral-sounding phrase that can be used in a CV. The goal is to signify that the only reason for the lack of the degree is the thesis, not failed classes or anything similar.

Comment: "ABD" if the degree is PhD.  It stand for All But Dissertation.

Comment: In this case, it would be a master's, I'll update the question.

Comment: Graduate work in XXX.

Comment: Question is better suited for http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "All class requirements [or _coursework_] for master's degree met" is a neutral/positive way to frame "hasn't completed thesis," I think.

Comment: I don't have an expression to suggest, however - especially if it's for a CV - I would discard expressions that aim too obviously at diverting the reader's attention from the missing completion of the thesis. It's very likely that the reader will wonder anyway why the writer stopped his/her master degree path at the very last step, so I'd favor an expression that is upfront about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a **candidate** because you are yet to finish your MS.

***Candidate*** -- [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candidate)

> (noun) 2. a student in the process of meeting final requirements for a degree
>   *"a PhD candidate"*